# How to prove surface S is part of a sphere？

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

Prove that a surface S is part of a sphere if and only if its second fundamental form is a nonzero-constant multiple of its first fundamental form. (Both of them are not zero)

I know for a sphere with radius r, rSFF=FFF, but I do not know how to prove it.

Comment: This is not true as written. For example, for a plane in $\Bbb R^3$, the second fundamental form is $II = 0 = 0 \cdot I$.

Comment: Thanks to reply. I know if second fundamental form is zero it is a part of plane. If both of them are not zero how to prove the above question.